# GAE, am I still required to implement a load balancer?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, saas

Have a production web-application deployment on GAE (LAMP Stack) with autoscaled setting, and according to the documentation, Google will automatically spin-up additional instances to meet demand; this seemed to have been proven when we went live, hours before a season finale aired which would guarantee traffic hit our site, and our site did NOT fall-over even with the expected sizable influx - so kudos to Google! However, I'd be naive to think that this server architecture is done, knowing that we're still in our infancy, and we could potentially get 10 - 100x more traffic in the near future on a consistent basis when we gain popularity and move into the global market. So my question is:

Should I be implementing a Load Balancer in GCP or will GAE be able to scale "indefinitely" to accommodate?

Comment: More details are required on exactly what you deployed on App Engine and which one, scaling settings, etc. Edit your questing with more details.

Comment: K, more details added to original post - let me know if still more information is required. Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: I don't see any of the requested information in your edit. For example, App Engine Standard or Flexible? Post your app.yaml.

Comment: App engine standard can scale automatically and quickly to a large number of servers so you can handle high volume.  I'm not aware of any traffic limits.  GAE flexible doesn't scale as quickly because it is much slower to spin up new instances. 
 I don't think that it is even possible to do your own load balancer with GAE standard or flexible.

Comment: In case where you want to be popular, Snapchat use AppEngine. If you have the same traffic/popularity, congrats!! Until this, I think you can be confident in the service scalability (if you set the right params!)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer: [AppEngine load balancing across multiple regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867277/appengine-load-balancing-across-multiple-regions) you'll need to implement the load balancer if you're targeting multiple regions.

Otherwise it will be dependent on your configuration and the thresholds you've set on your GAE config.

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed, there are three ways you can define scaling on your AppEngine instance:

> **Automatic scaling**
>
> - Automatic scaling creates dynamic instances based on request rate,    response latencies, and other application metrics. However, if you
>     specify a number of minimum idle instances, that specified number of
>     instances run as resident instances while any additional instances
>     are dynamic.
>
> **Basic Scaling**
>
> - Basic scaling creates dynamic instances when your application    receives requests. Each instance will be shut down when the app
>     becomes idle. Basic scaling is ideal for work that is intermittent or 
>     driven by user activity.
>
> **Manual scaling**
>
> - Manual scaling uses resident instances that continuously run the    specified number of instances regardless of the load level. This
>     allows tasks such as complex initializations and applications that
>     rely on the state of the memory over time.

So the answer is **it depends**. You'll just need to base your scaling strategy on how your load distribution looks. I would expect that the automatic scaling is fine for 90% of early-stage websites, though that's just my impression.

Comment: curious about the downvotes...And the edit seems a little strange as well.

Comment: The edit adds quoting to the list. You can see this by using the side-by-side markdown feature.